# Image Store Port Selection

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How does the Image Store Service choose it's ports? Right now, it looks to choose different ports every time Service Fabric starts, sometimes clashing with our application ports.

The ephemeral endpoint ports range is set, but the Image Store Service is still using ports inside the Application Ports Range. Our services have fixed ports.

I have not found a lot of documentation regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

SF system services rely on the ephemeral port range to communicate. Make sure there's no overlap between application port ranges and ephemeral port ranges.